# I'm trying to print an mysql query result into a jLabel

Tags: java, mysql, swing, formatting, jlabel

So instead of printing the result of a query into the Jlabel when i click another "show hint" label, the query statement itself is being printed into the jLabel

```
private void jLabel7MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

try
    {            
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");            
    Connection CC = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pulsedb", "root", "passtheword");
    String query = "SELECT hint FROM mstufflogin WHERE username = 'tapiwa'";            
    PreparedStatement PS = CC.prepareStatement(query);            
    PS.executeQuery(query);            
    jLabel6.setText("HINT: " + query);
}
```

output on the label will be....  `SELECT hint FROM mstufflogin WHERE username = 'tapiwa'`

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more what you want exactly?

Comment: OK...I want to click a label called "show hint" and when i click it i want it to show the the hint in another label and that hint is coming from a database table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the query with results of query

```
ResultSet result = PS.executeQuery();
result.next();
jLabel6.setText("HINT: " + result.getString(1));
```

Comment: Thank you ... It worked like a charm...My hint stored in the database showed up!

Answer (score -1):

I think you took the wrong variable(query)?

Try

```
jLabel6.setText("Hint:"+PS.getString("HINT"));
```